# How to test Mail Facade in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I cant seem to get the Mail Facade to accept a `->with()` command for Testing.

This works:

```
Mail::shouldReceive('send')->once();
```

But this does not work:

```
Mail::shouldReceive('send')->with('emails.welcome')->once();
```

and neither does this:

```
Mail::shouldReceive('send')->with('emails.welcome', array(), function(){})->once();
```

and neither does this:

```
Mail::shouldReceive('send')->with('emails.welcome', array(), function($message){})->once();
```

All give the following error:

```
"No matching handler found for Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::send("emails.welcome", Array, Closure)"
```

So how can I test Mail to check what it is receiving?

Also - for bonus points - is it possible to test what Mail is doing inside the closure? i.e. can I check what `$message->to()` is set to?

edit: my mail code:

```
Mail::send("emails.welcome", $data, function($message)
{
    $message->to($data['email'], $data['name'])->subject('Welcome!');
});
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The code examples below assumes PHP 5.4 or newer - if you're on 5.3 you'll need to add `$self = $this` before the following code and `use ($self)` on the first closure, and replace all references to `$this` inside the closure.

### Mocking SwiftMailer

The simplest way is to mock the Swift_Mailer instance. You'll have to read up on what methods exist on the Swift_Message class in order to take full advantage of it.

```
$mock = Mockery::mock('Swift_Mailer');
$this->app['mailer']->setSwiftMailer($mock);
$mock->shouldReceive('send')->once()
    ->andReturnUsing(function(\Swift_Message $msg) {
        $this->assertEquals('My subject', $msg->getSubject());
        $this->assertEquals('foo@bar.com', $msg->getTo());
        $this->assertContains('Some string', $msg->getBody());
    });
```

### Assertions on closures

Another way to solve this is to run assertions on the closure passed to `Mail::send`. This does not look all that clean, and its error messages can be rather cryptic, but it works, is very flexible, and the technique can be used for other things as well.

```
use Mockery as m;

Mail::shouldReceive('send')->once()
    ->with('view.name', m::on(function($data) {
        $this->assertContains('my variable', $data);
        return true;
    }), m::on(function($closure) {
        $message = m::mock('Illuminate\Mailer\Message');
        $message->shouldReceive('to')
            ->with('test@example.com')
            ->andReturn(m::self());
        $message->shouldReceive('subject')
            ->with('Email subject')
            ->andReturn(m::self());
        $closure($message);
        return true;
    }));
```

In this example, I'm running an assertion on the data passed to the view, and I'll get an error from Mockery if the recipient address, subject or view name is wrong.

`Mockery::on()` allows you to run a closure on a parameter of a mocked method. If it returns false, you'll get the "No matching handler found", but we want to run assertions so we just return true. `Mockery::self()` allows for chaining of methods.

If at any point you don't care what a certain parameter of a method call is, you can use `Mockery::any()` to tell Mockery that it accepts anything.

Comment: Andreas, Your answer is sooo good! I wish I could up vote it a dozen times!! :-) Thanks!

Comment: In L5 it should be `m::mock('Illuminate\Mail\Message')`, otherwise works without a change!